# RESOLVED React navigation not working react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am just giving a console.log (data) and navigating to another screen.

but I'm having the following error:

Component Exception
undefined is not an object

what am I doing wrong?

NOTE: When I use, navigation.goBack() works.

code below;

the error persists

Can anyone help me??

**CODE UPDATED**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Form } from '@unform/mobile';
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

import logo from '../../assets/logo.png';

import Input from '../../components/Input';
import Button from '../../components/Button';

import { Container, FormContainer, Title, TitleContainer } from './styles';

export default function SignUp() {
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSignUp = data => {
    console.log(data);
    navigation.navigate('SignUpPersonalData', { data });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' && 'padding'}
        enabled
      >
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
          <Container>
            <Image source={logo} />

            <TitleContainer>
              <Title>Crie sua conta</Title>
            </TitleContainer>

            <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
              <Input
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                name="email"
                icon="mail"
                placeholder="E-mail"
              />

              <Input
                secureTextEntry
                returnKeyType="send"
                name="password"
                icon="lock"
                placeholder="Senha"
              />

              <Button onPress={() => formRef.current.submitForm()}>
                Continuar
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Container>
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </>
  );
```

Screenshot error:

[image: error]

SX

Comment: with a normal callback you get the data ? if not put the code of your form component

Comment: I am getting the data through the ref of my input component, if I use State I will get the data normaly @anthonywillismuñoz

Comment: I check the offical snack demo and it not works when u send the data too. I recommend to use formik instead

Comment: I solve it, thanks all

Comment: Put an answer with the solution it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

don't use useCallback, try the following.

```
const handleSignUp = (data) =>{
    console.log(data);
    navigation.navigate('SignUpPersonalData',{data: data});
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with all of the code? including the imports statement?

Comment: the code looks okay to me. Where exactly is erring out? can you share a screenshot of the error?

Comment: the error is pointing to the SignUpPersonalData component, not the Signup component that you have listed. To confirm, navigate to a different component that you know works. or remove everything in the SignUpPersonalData component.